# Recurrence relation for a hypothetical recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

What is the method to find time complexity for recursive programs?
Let's take this code as an example.

```
int hypo(int a, int n) 
{ 
     if(n == 1) 
         return 0; 
     else 
         return a + hypo(a,n-1) * hypo(a,n-1); 
}
```

Comment: Figure out the cost of a single execution of `hypo` (without recursive calls) and figure out how many times the method will be called recursively.

Comment: In general you must do like what @MAV said, but you example is terrible, instead of return hypo(a,n-1) * hypo(a,n-1) simply find b = hypo(a,n-1); return b*2. you code have the must horrifying time complexity of 2^n, but if you do like what I told not only it would be polynomial but also it would be linear ;)

Comment: Basically with your code the time to get hypo(a, n) is the time to get hypo(a, n-1) twice. ie. t(a, n) = 2*t(a, n-1) also, t(a, 1) is basically 1 from there you can get the complexity

Comment: @piotrekg2 I disagree with Ali Amiri's comment and downvote. You should undelete your answer - it actually answers the question, gives a nice recurrence relation, and mentions how to speed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is write the equation that specifies the running time (this is often straightforward, and doesn't involve any solving). In your example, you denote by `f(a, n)` the running time of the function for parameters `a` and `n`, and then:

- `f(a, n)` doesn't depend on `a`, so let's write it `f(n)` instead
- `f(1)` is a constant; let's denote it by `k`
- If `n > 1`, then `f(n) = c + 2 * f(n-1)`, where `c` is a constant (another one)

So now you need to find out which function satisfies the equations `f(n) = c + 2 * f(n-1)` and `f(1) = k`. There is no general method, but in your case it's easy to calculate `f(2)`, `f(3)`, ...:

```
f(2) = c + 2 * f(1) =      c +  2 * k
f(3) = c + 2 * f(2) =  3 * c +  4 * k
f(4) = c + 2 * f(3) =  7 * c +  8 * k
f(5) = c + 2 * f(4) = 15 * c + 16 * k
```

It seems pretty easy to find `f(n)` from here (you can prove the formula by induction, or just say "it's obvious").

Answer (score 1):

Most simple problems of this form can be solved with the Master Theorem.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem.

More complex methods exist for more complex problems. :-)

Comment: The Master Theorem isn't actually applicable here. The recurrence has the wrong form.